# How does writing a 16-bit or 32-bit register affect its upper bytes?

Tags: assembly, x86

What values ​​will be saved in the upper part of registers after executing the following code in assembler?

```
mov ax, 100h
mov ebx, 123
mov ecx, 111
mov edx, ecx
```

Can someone explain?

Comment: By "older part", do you mean the upper 16 bits of the register?

Comment: Yes this is what i meant

Answer (score 2):

`mov ax, 100h` doesn't affect the upper bits of `eax`, so the result is undefined. Whatever was in the upper bits of the register before stays there.

The upper bits of `ebx` become a zero, because the constant 123 has zeros in its upper part.  Same for `ecx` and `edx`.